# Can I use Entity Framework 5 with VS 2013

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-6

If i want to use  **EF5 with VS 2013**  to create sample asp.net application using Grid view and Entity Data source , is it possible ? If yes, is there any post i can follow to create a sample application.

I am getting below error while using EF6 so that i would be able to use Entity Data Source easily.

I have already referred http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/02/28/announcing-the-release-of-dynamic-data-provider-and-entitydatasource-control-for-entity-framework-6.aspx article but have not got resolution for my problem.

[image: Error Message while using EF6[1]]

So I wanted to check if i am creating a new application, can i use EF5 with VS 2013 ?

Comment: try installing Entity Framework 5 with nuget. Here is an example:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/5.0.0

Comment: i already have EF6 installed on my machine and if i am creating  the project EF6 comes by default. Also i tried  PM> Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 5.0.0
No updates available for 'EntityFramework'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should uninstall the current version of Entity Framework, then install the version you would like.

```
Uninstall-package EntityFramework
Install-Package EntityFramework -version 5.0.0
```

You can also use the -force command at the end of the uninstall command to ignore dependencies.

Note that if you are planning on using asp.net identity, this will not work with Entity Framework 5

**EDIT**
Here is a screenshot after uninstalling the EntityFramework 6, and then installing EntityFramework 5 with the commands I gave you.

[image]

Comment: I have uninstalled the EF6.1.3 however getting below error while installing 5.0.0 
Is there something i am missing here ?

PM> install-package entityframework -version 5.0.0
install-package : Unable to find version '5.0.0' of package 'entityframework'.
At line:1 char:1
+ install-package entityframework -version 5.0.0
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Comment: I have tried this one a demo application now, and I have not had any problems. Are you running the uninstall first, and this is successfully removed before installing EF version 5?

Comment: Have a look at my packet manager console and make sure you are running the same commands

Comment: Thanks for the help,  the commands are working fine on one machine and not working on different machine. Still investigating on that.

Comment: How did you get it working, and what caused it not to work first time around?

Comment: I was using "Individual Authentication Accounts" and tried to remove the EF6 which has some dependency with authentication dll's.  When i selected "No Authentication" i was able to uninstall the EF6 completely and EF5 worked.